# How to avoid generation of a new random value when the response is submitted?

Tags: php

I want to create a small quiz where I choose a random question out of a sql and someone has to put in the right answer and then the next question will load.
My problem is that I have button1 for giving out the questions and buton2 to compare it to the answer of the user. But everytime button2 is clicked, another question will load which has another answer of course. Which looks kinda like :
click button 1: What is xy? , click button2: load another question :Who is ..? and compares your input to this queston.
Can I somehow save the question and not give out another random question while clicking on button2 ?

Right now this is my code to compare the answer from the user to the database:

```
$theme1 = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM Qustions WHERE theme = 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1');
$line1  = $theme1->fetch_assoc();
//show the question
if (isset($_POST['button1'])) {
    echo $line1['question'];
}

if (isset($_POST['button2'])) {
  if ($line1['answer']== $_POST['input']) {
    echo '<br>You are right !';
  }
  else if ($_POST['input'] == '') {
    echo 'please insert';
  }
  else {
    echo 'you\'re wrong';
  }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you should store the ID of the question that is shown anywhere?

Comment: @liv Please do not vandalize your question.

Answer (score 2):

Every time you press the button a new request is created and your data is lost.

You can store the question and the answer in session variables. How sessions work exactly you can read in the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php).

Here is an example of how you can solve this with sessions.

```
// start session
session_start();

// get a new question and store into session
if (isset($_POST['button1'])) {

    // get new data from database
    $theme1 = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM Qustions WHERE theme =1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1');
    $line1 = $theme1->fetch_assoc();
    
    $_SESSION['question'] = $line1['question'];
    $_SESSION['answer'] = $line1['answer'];

    echo $_SESSION['question'];
}

// check the answer 
if (isset($_POST['button2'])) {
    if ($_SESSION['answer'] == $_POST['input']) {
        echo '<br>You are right !';
    } else if ($_POST['input'] == '') {
        echo 'please insert';
    } else {
        echo 'you\'re wrong';
    }
}
```